# Getting confused with array access

Tags: c, arrays, output

In the following array:

```
float mat[2][2] = {{4.0, 3.0}, {2.0, 1.0}};
```

I'm not sure what is the type and the value of the following expressions:

```
"*mat"
"mat[0]"
"**mat"
"**(mat+1)"
```

When I try to run it, it always outputs addresses. I am a little bit confused now because I don't know if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2D array `mat`.

`*mat` and `mat[0]` are the same, they are (a pointer to) the first 1D array `{4.0, 3.0}`.
`mat[1]` would be a pointer to the second 1D array.

`**mat` is the first value of the first 1D array: `4.0`.

`*(mat + 1)` is `mat[1]`, the second 1D array, so `**(mat + 1)` is the first value of the second 1D array: `2.0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float mat[2][2] = {{4.0, 3.0}, {2.0, 1.0}}; 
    printf("%p\n", (void*)*mat);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)mat[0]);
    printf("%f\n", **mat);
    printf("%f\n", **(mat+1));
    return 0;
}
```

will print

```
0x7ffc9cc9e290
0x7ffc9cc9e290
4.000000
2.000000
```

the first 2 values are the address of the array, the value can be different for you, but they have to be the equal.

https://ideone.com/xEuxgg